# How can I add live stream to a playing video with minimal distraction?

Tags: video

I have a live stream of comments related to specific time slots in the video, I want to display them at their appropriate time during movie play without causing much distraction? Do you have suggestions for apps in which this was done in a nice way?

Comment: Welcome to UX.stackexchange. Aside from having the app "look nice" what specifically would you like to know? It's less a question of "should it be to the left or right" but how the users interact with the app (or where you want to lead the users).

Answer (score 3):

You can live stream comments or video meta data a couple different ways. I used soundcloud and genius.com as examples of good annotation and I think the mental models their users follow can translate well into video annotation.

1. Parallel Annotation

Similar to how Soundcloud operates with user comments on top of songs, this would simply display a user comment with a 'caret' for clear indication on the buffer bar/stream. This is probably the least distracting of the three options however it may not be the best way to deliver your content.

[image]

[image]

---

2. Parallel Annotation Layover

Almost working exactly the same as the first option however this overlays the comment on top of the video. Depending how important your meta data is this could be a viable solution. However if your comments and meta data are not necessary for viewing the video or enhancing the experience it could be a distraction for the user

[image]

3. Sidebar Annotation

Similar to how genius annotates lyrics and how other video players allow a live stream of comments side annotation gives you the best option for maximum real estate. If you have a large number of comments or meta data associated with a specific part of your video this would most likely be the best option.

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Scrolling tickers at the bottom of the screen are commonly used by large news/sports networks to display relevant information to viewers. As long you don't mind having a small overlay at the bottom of the screen this is an experience that the general public should be comfortable with.

Ticker examples:

[image]

[image]

Comment: The problem with a ticker is that @egsemsem wants contextual comments related to specific points in the video. Tickers as we know them (news + sports as you provided) usually provide additional information or broad context to what is being shown. Its hard to give specific comments or meta data to video with a ticker